# Datagrid resized by Columns

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid, resize

I've a problem with my datagrid. Every column has a MinWidth, so the user can see a part of every column. 2 columns have Width=* so they will resize with the window.

Now the costumer wants to resizes a column so the whole datagrid width will be bigger then the window size.. but that doesn't work, he can't resize.

Is there a way to do that? let the column resize the whole datagrid so it will get a scrollbar and its width is greater than the window width?